# Java : replaceAll and .split newline doesn't work

Tags: java, string, while-loop, bufferedreader

I am wanting to split a line up (inputLine) which is

```
Country: United Kingdom
City: London
```

so I'm using this code:

```
public void ReadURL() {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String inputLine = "";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String line = inputLine.replaceAll("\n", " ");
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        in.close();
    }   catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

when you run the method the the output is still

```
Country: United Kingdom
City: London
```

not like it's ment to be:

```
Country: United Kingdom City: London
```

now i've tried using

```
\n,\\n,\r,\r\n
```

and

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

but none of them work and using `replace`, `split` and `replaceAll` but nothing works.

so how do I remove the newlines to make one line of a String?

more detail: I am wanting it so I have two separate strings

```
String Country = "Country: United Kingdom";
```

and

```
String City = "City: London";
```

that would be great

Comment: Umm, well you are using `System.out.println` NOT `System.out.print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead of using `System.out.println(line);` use `System.out.print(line);`.

The new line is caused by the `println()` method which terminates the current line by writing the line separator string.

Comment: Wow and I didn't even realize, I knew it would have been something obvious -.-

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Read that. readLine method will not return any carriage returns or new lines in the text and will break input by newline. So your loop does take in your entire blob of text but it reads it line by line.

You are also getting extra newlines from calling println. It will print your line as read in, add a new line, then print your blank line + newline and then your end line + newline giving you exactly the same output as your input (minus a few spaces).

You should use print instead of println.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise taking a look at Guava [`Splitter.MapSplitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

In your case:

```
// input = "Country: United Kingdom\nCity: London"
final Map<String, String> split = Splitter.on('\n')
    .omitEmptyStrings().trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator(": ").split(input);
// ... (use split.get("Country") or split.get("City")
```